# Insert data into database without going to next screen in Java?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using JSP and Servlets to first display a Form in a JSP page then inserting all the parameters to a table in the servlet. Here is some of the code which I am using:

```
         <form action="ClassServlet" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="year">Year</label>
             <input type="text" name="year" id="year" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> 
             <label for="subject">Subject</label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="name">Name of your class</label> <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
             <input type="hidden"   name="teacher" id="teacher"
            <%
              out.println("value=\""+TeacherId+"\""); 
             %>               
              class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
             <input type="submit" value="Add">

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And for servlets:

```
                PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into TB_classes( CLASS_ID , CLASS_TEACHER_ID , CLASS_NAME , CLASS_YEAR ,  CLASS_SUBJECT) values (? , ? , ? , ? ,?) ");

        ps.setString(1, "3");
        ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("teacher"));
        ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("name1"));
        ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("year"));
        ps.setString(5, request.getParameter("subject"));

        ps.executeUpdate();
```

The code is working totally fine But being new to this I wanted to know is there any possible way to do same task  on one page. If yes then how ? Please help?

Comment: Have you heard of Ajax?

Comment: Yes but never tried(Actually I am working with J2ee first time).

Comment: Ajax is what solves your problem. Get the understanding of Ajax and see how you can add it to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a process called ajax.

Rather than going to a new page, you want to send a message to the server to do the insert but without making the page change.

Take a look at using jquery with a servlet, so the flow would be something like the following in javascript.

```
$.post('/servlet');
```

Then in that servlet, just do the insert SQL statement.

Take a look at the short example [here](http://nareshkumarh.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/jquery-ajax-json-servlet-example/) for further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

There are several technologies, which I only can recommend.

You could do it all in one servlet as follows:

- On HTTP GET (normal page call) fill the data *model* = do `request.setAttribute("TeacherId", teacherId);` and forward to the JSP with the form, the *view*.
- On HTTP POST (coming back from the form), do the SQL INSERT, and for the new case, call the doGet.

In the form use `${TeacherId}`.

To derive a new record ID from the database itself. In MySQL that would be an INT AUTO_INCR field. And the generated primary key could be retrieved as follows:

```
    ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into TB_classes"
        + "( CLASS_TEACHER_ID , CLASS_NAME , CLASS_YEAR ,  CLASS_SUBJECT) "
        + "values (? , ? , ? ,?)");

    ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("teacher"));
    ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("name1"));
    ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("year"));
    ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("subject"));

    ps.executeUpdate();

    ResultSet primaryKeysRS = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (primaryKeyRS.next()) {
        int classId = primaryKeyRS.getInt(1);
        ...
    }
    primaryKeysRS.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have both input and output on the same page with the use of XmlHttpRequest in java script.

The following code snippet should work out for you...

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("post", "ClassServlet", false);
xhReq.send(null);
var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
alert(serverResponse);
```

use this code on the click event of your submit button... then it will send the request to 'ClassServelet' and display the output in an alert box.